# Changing input fields in a Polymer template based on the selected value of a CoreSelector

Tags: polymer, dart-polymer

I've got an Add Stuff dialog which lets you choose the type of content you're adding. Based on this, I'd like to include or exclude certain fields.

```
<core-selector id="content-type" target="{{$['types']}}" itemsSelector="li" valueattr="value" selected="other"></core-selector>
  <ul id="types" class="list">
    <li value="announcement">Announcement</li>
    <li value="event">Event</li>
  </ul>
</core-selector>
```

I look into `$` to reference my fields, such as here:

```
addItem(Event e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  CoreSelector type = $['content-type'];
  CoreInput name = $['name'];
  CoreInput subject = $['subject'];
  CoreInput body = $['body'];
  ...
```

I'm listening to changes to the content type selector:

```
attached() {
  CoreSelector type = $['content-type'];
  type.addEventListener('core-select', (e) {
    selectedType = type.selected;
  });
}
```

(`selectedType` is observable: `@observable var selectedType;`.)

In the template itself, if I do:

```
<template if="{{selectedType == 'event'}}">
  <!-- Show some additional fields here. -->
</template>
```

The problem is then that `$` does not contain those fields because they didn't exist when the template was stamped (which is when `$` is populated).

What's a better way to approach all this?

What comes to my mind is this method of assigning all the form fields to an @observable Map as shown here: https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/forms/#binding-data. Would that be a better approach for what I'm trying to do, and if so how would I adapt that?

Comment: I didn't fully dive into your code but when `$` doesn't work because of `template repeate/if` just use `shadowRoot.querySelector()`. Your questions are IMHO sometimes a bit to broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, acknowledged. :) Many of my challenges are "is this the right way?" kind of things. I feel as if many others have these kinds of higher level challenges and could benefit from the answers. I'll try to do better.

Comment: I don't mind but the chances to get answers to such questions are rather low and I just wanted to make you aware what might be the reason. Maybe the Dart Google groups are a better place for this kind of questions.